# c# statusstrip toolstripstatuslabel updates after the process is over

Tags: c#, statusbar, statusstrip, toolstripstatuslabel

I have a method in which the program cycles through a load of data and I want it to put in the `toolstripstatuslabel1` the text `loading`, but for some reason it does this after it is done loading as opposed to while it is loading.  My `toolStripProgressBar1` however does update properly.  What might I be doing wrong?

```
toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "Acquiringdata for: " + name;
toolStripProgressBar1.Minimum = 0;
toolStripProgressBar1.Value = 1;
toolStripProgressBar1.Step = 1;

        for (int i = 8; i < data.Count; i++)
        {
            string newstr = data[i];
            string date = newstr.Substring(0, newstr.IndexOf(","));
            newstr = newstr.Substring(newstr.IndexOf(",") + 1);
            string close = newstr.Substring(0, newstr.IndexOf(","));
            newstr = newstr.Substring(newstr.IndexOf(",") + 1);
            string high = newstr.Substring(0, newstr.IndexOf(","));
            newstr = newstr.Substring(newstr.IndexOf(",") + 1);
            string low = newstr.Substring(0, newstr.IndexOf(","));
            newstr = newstr.Substring(newstr.IndexOf(",") + 1);
            string open = newstr.Substring(0, newstr.IndexOf(","));
            newstr = newstr.Substring(newstr.IndexOf(",") + 1);
            string volume = newstr.Substring(0);

            DataPoint dp = new DataPoint(date, close, high, low, open, volume);
            dataPoints.Add(dp);

            richTextBox1.Text += "New DataPoint Added: \n";

            toolStripProgressBar1.PerformStep();
            toolStripStatusLabel2.Text = (double)(i / (data.Count - 8))*100 + "%";
        }
```

Comment: You mean the first line `toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "Acquiringdata for: " + name;` doesn't update the `Label Text` ?

Answer (score 0):

The issue here was that I was running the process on my UI thread.